# How to create a custom base class which has a TableView, a Search & some edit functions, so as other class can inherit from it

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have many UITableViewController classes in my project. They have,

- Mostly the similar functions including search, edit, pull to refresh.
- A TableView
- A UISearchBar
- A UISearchDisplayController.

As I don't want to re-write all these functions each class, how do I create a custom  base class that has all these function.

I don't know how to do this?

Any tutorial link or some guidance will be of much help.

Comment: just create your base controller MyTableViewController inheriting from UITableViewController and have your others controller inhering from it instead of UITableViewController

Comment: @JeromeDiaz but how about the UISearchBar, edit function and pull-to-refresh control? How to create this base controller with all these built in?

Comment: @yongho : You should divide your problems into logical pieces. 1)Inheritance 2) UIsearch Bar 3) UITableView with refresh Control. Then later club those pieces together. What you have asked was mainly about inheritance, so we are providing you info about inheritance design.

Comment: @BalramTiwari so, I am asking how to club these pieces together.

Comment: @yongho : Ok fine. I will get you 1 & 2. Refresh control you try from your end. I will update my answer with that, just borrowing some minutes.

Comment: @yongho : I have updated some code. Just have a look. The approach of inheritance will always remain same, however you can change implementation as you want.

Comment: @yongho : Check the updated link for a sample project in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow simple inheritance concept of OOPS.

So here is a simple idea to proceed.

1. Create an new file, Name it like `myCustomTableBase` & type `UITableViewController` in `SubClass of` section in that dialog.
2. Now provide all your table related stuff & public method & objects in this base class.
3. Now create a new file again like `step1` & name it like `myNewHomeController` & type `myCustomTableBase` in `SubClass of` section in that dialog.
4. Once you are done with this file, you can check the `myNewHomeController.h` file for the inheritance path like this:

   ```
   #import "myCustomTableBase.h"
   @interface myNewHomeController : myCustomTableBase
   @end
   ```

Now its up to you how you design you base & subsequently inherit (subclass) your child classes out of it.

hope that helps.

**UPDATED CODE**

Please note: Here the base call is derrived from `UIviewController`, not the `UITableViewController`

`BaseViewController.h`

```
@interface btBaseViewController : UIViewController {
 UITableViewStyle _tableViewStyle;
 UISearchDisplayController *_searchController;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchBar *searchBar;

-(void)renderPadUI;   // should be implemented by derived class
-(void)renderPhoneUI; // should be implemented by derived class
```

`BaseViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self renderUI];
}


-(void)renderUI{
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

    if(IS_IPAD) {
        [self renderPadUI];
    }else {
        [self renderPhoneUI];
    }
}

-(void)enableSearchSetUp:(BOOL)show {
_searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width, 0)];
    _searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    _searchBar.delegate = self;
    _searchBar.placeholder = @"Search any keyword";
    [_searchBar sizeToFit];

    // Create search controller
    _searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];
    _searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    _searchController.searchResultsDelegate   = self;
    _searchController.delegate                = self;

    // add tableView
    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) style:_tableViewStyle];
    _tableView.delegate         = self;
    _tableView.dataSource       = self;
    _tableView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];

    // This is important line
    _tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchBar;

}
```

Now in any of your derived class from this class say `btHomeViewController`

`btHomeViewController.h`

```
#import "btBaseViewController.h"

@interface btHomeViewController : btBaseViewController

@end
```

`btHomeViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

// you need not to call this method from this class. The base/parent class will invoke this method, as soon as you create the instane of this class.

-(void)renderPhoneUI {
   [self enableSearchSetup:YES]; // this will base version
}
```

Also

- note that you have to implement the `-(void)renderPhoneUI` method as the base class is expecting child to implement this. Or else remove it from base then.
- you have to implement the `delegates` & `dataSource` for `UITableView` & `UISearchBar`, because I haven't provided any implementation of it in base. If you make give implementation of delegates in base class, then derived class can refer the same delegate's if not specifically implemented in derived class.
- `IS_IPAD` is a custom Macro to detect the device version using `UIDevice` class. Search about it, you will get its definition.
- this approach gives to a single code that handles TableView implementation with search which is in base class. If you want any customization to tableView & search bar in derived class, then you can do that the customization in specific class's `renderPhoneUI` method.
- I would suggest to implement all the `delegates` in base class itself. Then all you tableView & search, across app will be consistent. Just keep playing/updating with `dataSource`.
- If your tableview is different for each class, in terms of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation, then provide an implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in the intended class.

**[Here is sample code](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/problem-arc/tableViewBase.zip).**

I hope I have made more of the things clean & clear.

hope that helps.

Comment: Basically, I just write these function in base controller, but call it only in the sub classes? Nice approach.

Comment: @yongho : The most generic features should should go towards top, i.e Parent & the more specific features should move downwards in the hierarchy & to be implemented in Child. The subclass is different than parents for the things that it has of its own, rest all it inherits from parent. If the sample project has helped you, don't forget to up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

The better way of doing this is , Create a Super class Say `BaseTableViewController` implement your base functionality in this class, and inherit other `UITableViewController` Classes from this Class. Like

```
    @interface BaseTableViewController : UITableViewController
     - (void)doSomething
    @end
```

And, Your other UITableViewController Classes should be like

```
    @interface FirstTableViewController : BaseTableViewController
```

And call `[super doSomething];`

Comment: I know this. But I don't know how to add the search bar, pull to refresh control, edit function in base controller so the sub classes  don't have to rewrite these again.